# Wrappers vs Adapters in C++

Tags: c++

What is the difference between wrappers and adapters?

Since they both wrap around another object and provide additional functionallity why are there two separate names?

Also the STL smart pointers are wrappers or adapters?

Comment: IMO this question is little bit too broad for SO. Try Programmers.com or make it more specific. What they are you can read on Wikipedia...

Comment: "Wrapper" is more general than "Adapter". A wrapper is just an object whose responsibility is to contain some other object. Adapter typically refers to the GoF pattern, which is for providing an alternative interface to an object. Another example of a pattern that can also be considered a wrapper, is the Decorator pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrappers typically store a primitive type and add operations that the type does not support / support poorly-erroneously.

Adapters are used when the interface of a class is not exactly what is needed and provide a wrapping effect while changing the interface.

A way to distinguish the two, is that often an adapter is implemented by private inheritance. This kind of implementation is not usually available for wrappers that wrap a primitive.

Based on this I would call smart pointers **wrappes**

Answer (score 4):

It is almost the same. The only difference is that if your class provides new interface with the same (or almost the same) functionality as base one it is better to call it *adapter*.

If you class adds some new functionality (for example some additional processing of base class output) it is better to call it *wrapper*.

Smart pointers are *wrappers* because they add additional functionality (reference counting) to base class.

Answer (score 2):

The word "wrapper" is extremely **overloaded** in software engineering. You use it when you don't want to (or cannot) be more specific. Basically, every time you add an additional layer around something so that this "something" cannot (or should not) be accessed directly anymore, you "wrap" it, whatever the reason may be. The wrapped component may be too low-level, it may be incomplete, you may want to add caching to it, you may simply want to reduce compile time... or whatever reason you can think of. The word "wrapper" alone does not tell you more than that.

Therefore, nobody will object when you say that a smart pointer is a wrapper around a raw pointer. A smart pointer prevents direct access to the raw pointer (or allows it if you need to but reminds you that you should not do it normally). That makes it a wrapper.

"Adapter" is a slightly more specific word. It means that a software component has exactly the features you need but exposes them in a **formally wrong way**, so you add a layer around the original component just to make its interface conform to your needs. Adapting something is a special case of wrapping. I would not call a smart pointer an adapter. "Adapting" implies that the functionality is basically unchanged but only the names and formalities of the interface are different -- which is not true for smart pointers.

Summary:

- "Wrapper" = Adding a layer around a software component for *any* reason.
- "Adapter" = Wrapping with the reason being nothing more than an *incompatible
  interface*.